# Combinatorial vs. geometric symmetries of graphs and their drawings

Tags: geometry, graph-theory

Associated with a graph $G$ and its automorphism group $\text{Aut}(G)$ (reflecting its combinatorial symmetries) are drawings in the plane with - eventually - one or more (geometric) symmetry groups.

For example the [Petersen graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petersen_graph) with automorphism group $S_5$ can be drawn with symmetry groups $D_1$, $D_5$ ([dihedral groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dihedral_group)), or [cyclic group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_group) $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$.

> What can be said about possible combinations of geometric symmetry
>   groups of graph drawings and their dependence on the automorphism
>   group of the graph?

Is there for example always exactly one largest geometric symmetry group?

(Note that there are graphs with non-trivial automorphism group which don't admit a symmetric drawing in the plane at all:

[image]

So on what else than the automorphism group does it depend whether there are geometric symmetries? Are there graphs with arbitrarily large automorphism group but without a symmetric drawing?)

Comment: What do you assume about the "geometric symmetries" except that they move vertices and edges as expected? Are they to be plane isometries? Homeomorphisms?

Comment: I mean rotations and reflections. (What risk of confusion is there?)

Comment: None anymore, I think.

Comment: I should have asked: What risk of confusion *was* there?

Comment: There is a theorem to the effect that every finite group is the automorphism group of some graph. This is Frucht's Theorem, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frucht's_theorem

Comment: I am aware of Frucht's Theorem, but to be honest, I cannot see immediately how it answers my question.

Comment: Well, it says there are graphs with an arbitrarily large automorphism group that don't have a drawing with that automorphism group. But maybe by "without a symmetric drawing" you mean no drawing of that group has any symmetry at all?

Comment: I mean the latter.

Comment: Can you give an example of a graph with non-trivial automorphism group, with no symmetric drawing?

Comment: Thanks. So, what happens if you take a complete graph $K_n$ and attach a little 4-vertex non-symmetrical doohickey to one vertex? Don't you get an automorphism group of $S_{n-1}$, with no symmetric drawing?